# jqgrid reset filters causes a crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jqgrid

I m working on a jqgrid table, i ve set it up and works fine with one exception.
By pressing the reset button on advanced search(remove all filters),javascript is crashing with error
**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data** 
The table is freezing with loading gif. 
[image]
The json from server is ok nor i have an open bracket to my code and everything else works fine.

I use save column and filter state but removed them and keep getting the crash.
Posting the code below of jqgrid and funcs i m using

```
cm = [
                {label: 'id', name: 'id', index: 'id', sortable: false, width: '50', hidden: true},
                {label: 'Actions', name: 'act', index: 'act', sortable: false, search: false, resizable: false, width: '80'},
                {label: 'UserName', name: 'User.username', index: 'User.username', sorttype: 'string', width: '140'},
                {label: 'Όνομα', name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', sorttype: 'string', width: '140'},
                {label: 'Επίθετο', name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', sorttype: 'string', width: '140'},
                {label: 'Τμήμα', name: 'Department.Description', index: 'Department.Description', sorttype: 'string', formatter: 'select', width: '180'},
                {label: 'Ρόλος', name: 'Role.Description', index: 'Role.Description', sorttype: 'string', width: '110'},
                {label: 'Τηλέφωνο', name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', sorttype: 'string', width: '110'},
                {label: 'Κινητό', name: 'MobilePhone', index: 'MobilePhone', sorttype: 'string', width: '110'},
                {label: 'Διεύθυνση', name: 'Address', index: 'Address', sorttype: 'string', width: '180'},
                {label: 'Ημ/νία Δημ/γίας', name: 'CreatedDay', index: 'CreatedDay', width: '100',
                    sorttype: 'string',
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'],
                        // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                        // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                // id: 'orderDate_datePicker',
                                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                                minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                onSelect: function () {
                                    if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                                        // in case of searching toolbar
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                                        }, 50);
                                    } else {
                                        // refresh the filter in case of
                                        // searching dialog
                                        $(this).trigger('change');
                                    }
                                }
                                // showOn: 'focus'
                            }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                },
                {label: 'Ώρα Δημ/γίας', name: 'CreatedTime', index: 'CreatedTime', width: '150',
                    sorttype: 'date', formatter: 'date',
                    formatoptions: {srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d-m-Y H:i:s"},
                    searchoptions: {
                        //sopt: ['cn'],
                        // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                        // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                        dataInit: function (element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                // id: 'orderDate_datePicker',
                                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                                minDate: new Date(2010, 0, 1),
                                maxDate: new Date(2020, 0, 1),
                                onSelect: function () {
                                    if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                                        // in case of searching toolbar
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                                        }, 50);
                                    } else {
                                        // refresh the filter in case of
                                        // searching dialog
                                        $(this).trigger('change');
                                    }
                                }
                                // showOn: 'focus'
                            }
                            );
                        }
                    }},
            ],
                    //load options for select menu 
                    setSearchSelect = function (response) {
                        this.jqGrid("setColProp", "Role.Description", {
                            edittype: 'select',
                            editoptions:
                                    {value: response.roles},
                            stype: "select",
                            searchoptions: {
                                clearSearch: false,
                                value: response.roles,
                                sopt: ["eq"]
                            }
                        });

                        this.jqGrid("setColProp", "Department.Description", {
                            edittype: 'select',
                            editoptions:
                                    {value: response.departments},
                            stype: "select",
                            searchoptions: {
                                clearSearch: false,
                                value: response.departments,
                                sopt: ["eq"]
                            }
                        });
                    };

            //select2 init 
            filterToolbarOptions = {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn"},
            removeAnyOption = function ($form) {
                $form.find("select.input-elm")
                        .each(function () {
                            $(this).find("option[value='']").remove();
                        });
                return true; // for beforeShowSearch only
            },
                    initSelect2 = function (element) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(element).select2({
                                // add "ui-widget" class to have the same font-family like in jQuery UI Theme
                                // add "ui-jqdialog" class to have font-size:11px like in other items of jqGrid form
                                dropdownCssClass: "ui-widget ui-jqdialog"
                            }).prev(".select2-container")
                                    .find(">.select2-choice")
                                    .find(">.select2-arrow").css("background-color", "transparent");
                            $(element).on("select2-open", function () {
                                $(element).prev(".select2-container")
                                        .find(">.select2-choice")
                                        .addClass("ui-state-default");
                            })
                                    .on("select2-close", function () {
                                        $(this).prev(".select2-container")
                                                .find(">.select2-choice")
                                                .removeClass("ui-state-default");
                                    });
                        }, 50);
                    },
                    //save table column state functions
                    numberSearchOptions = ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'],
                    numberTemplate = {formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number',
                        searchoptions: {sopt: numberSearchOptions}},
            myDefaultSearch = 'cn',
                    getColumnIndex = function (grid, columnIndex) {
                        var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                            if ((cm[i].index || cm[i].name) === columnIndex) {
                                return i; // return the colModel index
                            }
                        }
                        return -1;
                    },
                    refreshSerchingToolbar = function ($grid, myDefaultSearch) {
                        var postData = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'), filters, i, l,
                                rules, rule, iCol, cm = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'),
                                cmi, control, tagName;
                        for (i = 0, l = cm.length; i < l; i++) {
                            control = $("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(cm[i].name));
                            if (control.length > 0) {
                                tagName = control[0].tagName.toUpperCase();
                                if (tagName === "SELECT") { // && cmi.stype === "select"
                                    control.find("option[value='']")
                                            .attr('selected', 'selected');
                                } else if (tagName === "INPUT") {
                                    control.val('');
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (typeof (postData.filters) === "string" &&
                                typeof ($grid[0].ftoolbar) === "boolean" && $grid[0].ftoolbar) {

                            filters = $.parseJSON(postData.filters);
                            if (filters && filters.groupOp === "AND" && typeof (filters.groups) === "undefined") {
                                // only in case of advance searching without grouping we import filters in the
                                // searching toolbar
                                rules = filters.rules;
                                for (i = 0, l = rules.length; i < l; i++) {
                                    rule = rules[i];
                                    iCol = getColumnIndex($grid, rule.field);
                                    if (iCol >= 0) {
                                        cmi = cm[iCol];
                                        control = $("#gs_" + $.jgrid.jqID(cmi.name));
                                        if (control.length > 0 &&
                                                (((typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "undefined" ||
                                                        typeof (cmi.searchoptions.sopt) === "undefined")
                                                        && rule.op === myDefaultSearch) ||
                                                        (typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "object" &&
                                                                $.isArray(cmi.searchoptions.sopt) &&
                                                                cmi.searchoptions.sopt.length > 0 &&
                                                                cmi.searchoptions.sopt[0] === rule.op))) {
                                            tagName = control[0].tagName.toUpperCase();
                                            if (tagName === "SELECT") { // && cmi.stype === "select"
                                                control.find("option[value='" + $.jgrid.jqID(rule.data) + "']")
                                                        .attr('selected', 'selected');
                                            } else if (tagName === "INPUT") {
                                                control.val(rule.data);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(elem).datepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                                autoSize: true,
                                //showOn: 'button', // it dosn't work in searching dialog
                                changeYear: true,
                                changeMonth: true,
                                showButtonPanel: true,
                                showWeek: true,
                                onSelect: function () {
                                    if (this.id.substr(0, 3) === "gs_") {
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                                        }, 50);
                                    } else {
                                        // to refresh the filter
                                        $(this).trigger('change');
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }, 100);
                    },
                    saveObjectInLocalStorage = function (storageItemName, object) {
                        if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                            window.localStorage.setItem(storageItemName, JSON.stringify(object));
                        }
                    },
                    removeObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
                        if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                            window.localStorage.removeItem(storageItemName);
                        }
                    },
                    getObjectFromLocalStorage = function (storageItemName) {
                        if (typeof window.localStorage !== 'undefined') {
                            return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(storageItemName));
                        }
                    },
                    myColumnStateName = 'ColumnChooserAndLocalStorage1.colState',
                    saveColumnState = function () {
                        var colModel = this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = colModel.length, colItem, cmName,
                                postData = this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData'),
                                columnsState = {
                                    search: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'search'),
                                    page: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page'),
                                    rowNum: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum'),
                                    sortname: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname'),
                                    sortorder: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder'),
                                    permutation: this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'remapColumns'),
                                    colStates: {}
                                },
                        colStates = columnsState.colStates;
                        if (typeof (postData.filters) !== 'undefined') {
                            columnsState.filters = postData.filters;
                        }

                        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                            colItem = colModel[i];
                            cmName = colItem.name;
                            if (cmName !== 'rn' && cmName !== 'cb' && cmName !== 'subgrid') {
                                colStates[cmName] = {
                                    width: colItem.width,
                                    hidden: colItem.hidden
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        saveObjectInLocalStorage(myColumnStateName, columnsState);
                    },
                    restoreColumnState = function (colModel) {
                        var colItem, i, l = colModel.length, colStates, cmName,
                                columnsState = getObjectFromLocalStorage(myColumnStateName);
                        if (columnsState) {
                            colStates = columnsState.colStates;
                            for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                                colItem = colModel[i];
                                cmName = colItem.name;
                                if (cmName !== 'rn' && cmName !== 'cb' && cmName !== 'subgrid') {
                                    colModel[i] = $.extend(true, {}, colModel[i], colStates[cmName]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return columnsState;
                    },
                    firstLoad = true;
            myColumnsState = restoreColumnState(cm);
            isColState = typeof (myColumnsState) !== 'undefined' && myColumnsState !== null;
            //end save table state functions

            jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('searchGrid', {multipleSearch: true});
            //the grid options
            $grid = $("#jqgrid"),
                    $grid.jqGrid({
                        url: '{{ path('admin_profiles_json') }}',
                        datatype: "json",
                        colModel: cm,
                        loadonce: true,
                        width: null,
                        autowidth: true,
                        pager: '#jqGridPager',
                        toolbarfilter: true,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        pgtext: null,
                        pgbuttons: false,
                        pagination: false,
                        hoverrows: false,
                        //shrinkToFit: false,
                        rowNum: isColState ? myColumnsState.rowNum : 10000,
                        page: isColState ? myColumnsState.page : 1,
                        search: isColState ? myColumnsState.search : false,
                        postData: isColState ? {filters: myColumnsState.filters} : {},
                        sortname: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortname : 'CreatedTime',
                        sortorder: isColState ? myColumnsState.sortorder : 'desc',
                        treeGrid: false,
                        grouping: true,
                        caption: "Χρήστες",
                        multiselect: false,
                        groupingView: {
                            //groupField: ["Requestor.AlliasName"],
                            groupColumnShow: [true],
                            groupText: ['<b>{0}  count({1})</b>'],
                            groupOrder: ["asc"],
                            groupSummary: [false],
                            groupCollapse: true

                        },
                        gridComplete: function () {
                            var ids = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                                var cl = ids[i];
                                be = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Edit Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').editRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>";
                                se = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Save Row' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').saveRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-save'></i></button>";
                                ca = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' data-original-title='Cancel' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('" + cl + "');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
                                //ce = "<button class='btn btn-xs btn-default' onclick=\"jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\"><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>";
                                //jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
                                jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], {
                                    act: be + se + ca
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {

                        },
                        beforeProcessing: function (response) {
                            setSearchSelect.call($grid, response);
                            var $self = $(this),
                                    options = jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), p,
                                    //options = response.colModelOptions, p,
                                    needRecreateSearchingToolbar = false;
                            if (options !== null) {
                                for (p in options) {
                                    if (options.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                                        if (options[p].edittype === "select") {
                                            options[p].editoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
                                        }
                                        if (options[p].stype === "select") {
                                            options[p].searchoptions.dataInit = initSelect2;
                                        }
                                        $self.jqGrid("setColProp", p, options[p]);
                                        if (this.ftoolbar) { // filter toolbar exist
                                            needRecreateSearchingToolbar;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (needRecreateSearchingToolbar) {
                                    $self.jqGrid("destroyFilterToolbar");
                                    $self.jqGrid("filterToolbar", filterToolbarOptions);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        loadComplete: function () {

                            var $this = $(this);
                            if (firstLoad) {
                                firstLoad = false;
                                if (isColState && myColumnsState.permutation.length > 0) {
                                    $this.jqGrid("remapColumns", myColumnsState.permutation, true);
                                }
                                if (typeof (this.ftoolbar) !== "boolean" || !this.ftoolbar) {
                                    // create toolbar if needed
                                    $this.jqGrid('filterToolbar', {stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn"});
                                    setTimeout(function () {
                                        $grid[0].triggerToolbar();
                                    }, 50);
                                }
                            }

                            refreshSerchingToolbar($this, myDefaultSearch);
                            saveColumnState.call($this);

                        },
                        sortable: function () {
                            saveColumnState.call($grid);
                        },
                        resizeStop: function () {
                            //$("#jqGrid").trigger("resize");
                            saveColumnState.call($grid);
                        },
                        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, e)
                        {
                            var myGrid = $('#jqgrid'),
                                    selectedRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
                                    cellValue = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'id');
                            modalprofile(cellValue);
                        },
                    });
            //end grid otions

            //extend grid options
            $.extend($.jgrid.search, {
                multipleSearch: true,
                multipleGroup: true,
                recreateFilter: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                showQuery:true
            });
```

Comment: **Which fork of jqGrid (old jqGrid version <=4.7, [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) or [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) you use and in which version?** Do you tried to use non-minimized version of jqGrid (something like `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`) in debugger. In which line of `jquery.jqgrid.src.js` you have the JSON error or in which line of your code? Do you have the demo, test data with the test case which can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I was using 4.7.1 just now change it to 4.8.2 and its ok not crashing thnx! By the way by pressing the reset button all data comes back like there is no filter but the column filters is not cleared even if they are not applied. any idea how i ll clear the after reset?

Comment: I suppose that your code do have some problem, but one need to have test case to reproduce it. I seen you use some parts of my old code, so I decide to post you. Could you change the URLs (at least temporary) and verify that you will not have the problem with free jqGrid don't have the problem. You need to use URLs from [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit). I suppose that you can have some problems with restoring the **old state data** from the `localStorage`, but one need have demo and the test case.

Comment: Almost everything is from your demos ;) I change the urls and now i ve the same problem again after pressing reset button table is crashing with loading gif and error at the console of browser  unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data but with 4.8.2 works fine also restoring the state of table works fine. The only think not works is what mention before if i add some filters at the toolbar and open the andvanced search and reset, data is resseting but filters on the column headers are still there? is somthing like callback after the reset to clear it there?

Comment: Actually the save column state worked for me ok only in 4.7.1 not in 4.8.2 or your urls

Comment: The most problem in saving the state is the following. You save the state under one conditions with one server side code and then you restore the state in another conditions or with changed server code (some new column in the grid and so on). I develop my own fork of jqGrid: free jqGrid. If you could post the demo with description of the test case I could debug the demo, find the reason and fix the code of free jqGrid. I posted many fixes or feature requests before, but now it's all much more simple. So If you want I can analyse the problem if you have the demo which reproduce it.

Comment: i ll try to make demo there thnx